# Xcode Property Not Retaining Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, properties, nsstring

I have a view controller called LoginWindowViewController.h that declared a property called usernameTextField:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;
```

A string called James is associated to this TextField.
I then import another view controller,FirstViewController.h into my LoginWindowViewController.m and I also imported LoginWindowViewController.h  into FirstViewController.m . In my FirstViewController.h there is a property called username.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *userName;
```

Then i assign usernameTextField to username(In my FirstViewController.m). But when i NSlog the property username in my FirstViewController.m, it gives a null value.How do i fix this?

Comment: Why NSString` is an `IBOutlet`? Plus it's unclear the "import" thing. When do you logs? How do you log exactly? Shouldn't `IBOutlet` be `weak`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be an IBOutlet to be accessible from other .m files?

Comment: I used #import "header file" to import.

Comment: But does the view exists? How are you checking its value? My guess: You're creating a whole new object.

Comment: Yes both view controllers exist and we are just importing a property from one view controller to another but it will not retain it's value.For example,we assign a string to usernameTextField in one view controller,but when we import the property into another view controller and  use NSLog to log it's string,the value becomes null

Comment: Show how you try to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import classes you do not actually import any values. When you set the value of a property it is only set on that instance of the class. You will need to explicitly reference the property of your current instance to get the value you have set.

One note: IBOutlet stands for Interface Builder Outlet and is how you create a link from a storyboard or xib file UI element to a class property. So, no need to use IBOutlet if you are not linking to something in interface builder.

String should be declared

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userName;
```

Then when you instantiate your login view controller from first view controller you can set the property like this

```
LoginWindowViewController *loginVC = [[LoginWindowViewController alloc] init];
[loginVC.usernameTextField setText:self.userName];
```